# replace a particular row and column value of one file with another

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file containing

```
a b c d
g h i j
d e f f
```

and a another file containing

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 1 0 1
```

I know that I can extract a particular row and column using

```
awk 'FNR == 2 {print $3}' fit_detail.txt
```

But, I need to replace 2nd column and 3rd row of first file with the 2nd row and 3rd column of second file. How I could do this and saves it into another file.

Finally, my output should look like

```
a b c d
g h i j
d 1 f f
```

Comment: Please clarify how it will look after the desired transformation.

Comment: do you forget what language do you using? (tagged for perl awk sed shell) :)

Comment: @MarkSetchell added my final output.

Comment: @jm666: Either from awk or sed language. Anyway thanks I got nice answer from  John1024

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR && NR==3 {a=$2} NR==FNR {next} FNR==3 {$2=a} {print}' file2 file1
a b c d
g h i j
d 1 f f
```

Explanation:

- `NR==FNR && NR==3 {a=$2}`

  In `awk`, `NR` is the number of records (lines) that have been read in total and `FNR` is the number of records (lines) that have been read in from the current file.  So, when `NR==FNR`, then we know that we are working on the first file named on the command line.  For that file, we select only the third row (`NR==3`) and save the value of its second column in the variable `a`.
- `NR==FNR {next}`

  If we are processing the first named file on the command line, skip to `next` line.
- `FNR==3 {$2=a}`

  Because of the preceding `next` statement, it is only possible to get to this command if we are now working on the second named file.  For this file, if we are on the third row, change the 2nd column to the value `a`.
- `{print}`

  All lines from the second named file are printed.

#### Controlling the output format

By default, `awk` separates output fields with a space.  If another output field separator, such as a tab, is desired, it can be specified as follows:

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" 'NR==FNR && NR==3 {a=$2} NR==FNR {next} {$2=$2} FNR==3 {$2=a} {print}' file2 file1
a       b       c       d
g       h       i       j
d       1       f       f
```

To accomplish this, we made two changes:

1. The output field separator (OFS) was specified as a tab with the `-v` option:  `-v OFS="\t"`
2. When using a simple print statement, such as `{print}`, `awk` will normally apply the new output field separator only if the line had been changed in some way. That is accomplished here with the statement `$2=$2`.  This assigns the second field to itself.  Even though this leaves the second field unchanged, it is enough to trigger awk` to replace the old field separators with new ones on output.

Comment: Thanks. But If I need to print every word with tab then what should I do?

Comment: @ramkrishna Answer updated with a tab-separated version.

Comment: I just want to thanks because through this post I learned a lot regarding awk command working. And it is helping me a lot. Thanks again.